# MFC - launch external application after exit

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to online update my C++ MFC application.
I can download update file from http, but the problem is, that I need to overwrite the file currently in use. So, can I launch external application from MFC program (e.g. SFX archive) after program exit?

Comment: A great collection of implementations for what you are basically trying to do: [Self-deleting Executables](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/self-deleting-executables).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the function [atexit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit)

In the function you provide you could launch the process that downloads the file.

E.g.

```
void launchDownload(void)
{
  ShellExecute(...);
}

...

atexit(launchDownload);
```

See also [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: void CUpmApp::rtx()
{
} 

....
atexit(rtx);

Causes error: error C3867: 'CUpmApp::rtx': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: Your function needs to be static if you are to include it like that so that the linker finds it. e.g. `static void CUpmApp::rtx() {] .. atexit(CUpmApp::rtx);`